Mvn Java automation inside a crossPlatform Monorepo codebase
I'm working on Integrating my existing Java automation framework(selenium) into a mono repo codebase, as shown below. Monorepo codebase is mainly a cross-platform frontend code that uses React Native, JS, and NX to build.
My mono repo structure

Currently I have created a separate folder inside of monoreopo named integration_tests using mvn wrapper and placed all the core logic and automated tests.
I'm asked to Distribute  test cases which are in my java/src/test into respective feature folders i.e, inside libs/features
How can I achieve this? I just want to move the tests (java test class files alone) into respective folders inside libs/features.
One option I have in mind is to create multi-module project
